# Casperjs - get a list of all elements, then perform actions on each member of returned array

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm new to Casperjs and I'm trying to iterate over an array of elements and perform Casper-related tasks on them. However, I'm having trouble retrieving the array of objects on which I want to perform these Casper tasks. I'm selecting a list of all the elements using this function

```
getLinks = ->
  links = document.getElementsByClassName('text-item')
```

and then evaluating the function with

```
casper.then( ->
  links = this.evaluate(getLinks)
)
```

And finally trying to print out the array with

```
casper.run( ->
  this.echo(links).exit()
)
```

But all that is being returned is `[object Object]`. What am I doing wrong? When I run `document.getElementsByClassName('text-item')` in browser, an array of `<p>` tags (what I'm looking for) is returned, so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use evaluate to return objects.

You should try to put the raw data you need ( the text information in your case ) in an array and return this array rather than returning an object array.

Another way that might work ( untested thought ) is to use JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() to bypass evaluate() limitations.